# Access 2007 button click event error

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a following code in my access vba on button click event. Idea is to use temporary variable to forward a value from textbox into the subform:

```
Private Sub button_novi_ir_Click()
    On Error GoTo button_novi_ir_Click_Err

    On Error Resume Next
    TempVars("brojRN").Value = Me.brojRNtxt
    DoCmd.OpenForm "PODACI_O_IZVRŠENIM RADOVIMA_FORM", acNormal, "", "", acAdd, acNormal
    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If

button_novi_ir_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

button_novi_ir_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume button_novi_ir_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Each time i click the button I get an error message "A problem occurred while MS Office Access was communicating with the OLE server or ActiveX Control". I really have no idea what to do about it. So, please can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the accented character in your form name is an issue - I'll assume it isn't. But you shouldn't supply the empty strings "" for the FilterName and WhereCondition arguments, just use commas to skip these arguments ,,,

And this is code, not a macro, so you should be using the `Err` object and examine its `Err.Number` and `Err.Description`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the form name to remove local character and I have removed empty strings and changed error handling, but still it doesn't work. It didn't work even when I was using Macro, that's why I tried code.